# Should I use a paired or unpaired t-test for this problem?

Tags: t-test

I tested 5 objects with two different devices each, but on the last test for the second device, there was an error so the value was unusable (ie on objects 1-5, first device series was 1,1,2,2,3 and second series was 1,2,2,2,X).  Should I use n=5 for the first device and n=4 for the second device and use an unpaired (heteroscedastic) test or should I throw out the good value for the last test of the first device and use a paired t-test with n=4 for both devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your small samples, you should use a permutation test. Here is a link with further information if you want to do it in R: [How to compare two datasets using metrics drawn from unknown distributions and with small sample sizes?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58409/how-to-compare-two-datasets-using-metrics-drawn-from-unknown-distributions-and-w)

Comment: However, doesn't this test assume that the results are independent of each other?  Since both devices were tested on each object once, I though they should remained paired as much as possible...

Comment: There is a paired permutation test. Google it to get details.